# Unable to run Python Unittest Selenium scripts by invoking Chrome driver after creating Pyinstaller package

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pyinstaller

I'm creating a standalone package to run on Windows so that my client does not need to install any IDE or Python or Selenium, etc.

My automation test scripts are developed using the below things:
Python 3.x unittest framework
Selenium (Chrome driver)
Openpyxl to read/write excel files

In addition, the scripts are using some paths from settings.ini file.

Moreover, my scripts are in different Python directories/packages as follows:

Main folder

------------Test Cases (Python package)
--------------------------- test_main_driver.py
------------Page Objects (Python package)
---------------------------** home.py
---------------------------** dashboard.py
------------Utils (Python package)
---------------------------** string_util.py

test_main_driver.py invokes chrome driver and imports other packages, also have test class, setup and test methods
** contain code

I'm using Pyinstaller to create standalone package using spec file, but whenever I execute exe file after creating package, empty cmd appears and closes.

To debug the problem, I've tried simple automation scripts without using unittest framework (even without defining classes or methods). It worked fine after fixing path issues and creating exe. In same scripts, I used openpyxl but that didn't work either.

It seems to me that main problem is "Python's unittest framework". After it, second problem would be to correct the paths of packages I'm using in main test driver file. However, below is the code I'm using to solve unittest related issue after creating exe.

Chrome is invoked using the below code (without classes/methods/packages/unittest) after making package using Pyinstaller:

```
current_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]))
chromedriver = os.path.join(current_folder, "..\\..\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Chrome is not invoked using the below code (with classes/methods/unittest) after making package using Pyinstaller:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
    current_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]))
        chromedriver = os.path.join(current_folder, "..\\..\\chromedriver.exe")
        print(chromedriver)
        time.sleep(5)
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)

    def test_method(self):
        self.driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['start.py'],
             pathex=['.....\\TestCases'],
             binaries=[(".....\\chromedriver.exe", ".")],
             datas=[(".....\\TTestData", ".")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='start',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
           [('chromedriver.exe', 'chromedriver.exe', 'DATA')],
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='start')
```

Comment: Open your output executable with CMD and put full error log here.

Comment: **Ran 0 tests in 0.000s OK** is the output when unittest code is run.